# Why do WP_Query results change after updating unrelated Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)?

Tags: php, wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

**TLDR** - *After manually updating a custom post, my `WP_Query` will change it's sorting order and move that updated post to the end of the array response.*

I have a custom post type called `Events` that use Advanced Custom Fields. I have written a shortcode that uses `WP_Query` to find all the `Events` that are `Open` and then sort them by their `final_deadline` first and their `priority` second.

Here are the arguments for my query:

```
$today_is = date('Y-m-d', time());

$open_events_args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'events',
        'offset' => 0,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'final_deadline' => array(
                'key' => 'final_deadline_date',
                'value' => $today_is,
                'compare' => '>=',
            ),
            'open_value' => array(
                'key' => 'is_open',
                'value' => 'Open',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            'priority' => array(
                'key' => 'event_priority',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            )
        ),
        'orderby' => array (
            'final_deadline' => 'ASC',
            'priority' => 'ASC',
        ),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids',
    );

    $the_open_query = new WP_Query($open_events_args);
    $open_events = $the_open_query->get_posts();
```

Many of my advanced custom fields are being set programmatically through an API call. What I found was the `WP_Query` initially returned correct results, but as soon as I manually updated an event post (without changing any of the fields), that post would move to the end of the `$open_events` array and be out of order.

If I updated another post, it too would move to the end of the array. Eventually the `open_events` array was bifurcated. The first section had events that were not manually updated, and the second section had events that were updated ... and each section was in the correct order.

I went ahead and manually updated my 17 events and figured that would fix it. However, now that I'm adding images to a new advanced custom field, this process is starting all over again. Updated events are moving to the end of the array and out of order.

Does anyone know what would cause this and how I can fix it? Updating an unrelated custom field should not be affecting my `WP_Query`, but it keeps happening and I'm not sure why.

Thanks.